# Javascript remove background color and opacity

Tags: javascript, html, css, background, opacity

How can I remove the background-color and opacity property using Javascript only (no Jquery!).

I tried this:

```
document.getElementById('darkOverlay').style.removeProperty("background-color");
document.getElementById('darkOverlay').style.removeProperty("opacity");
```

but it did not work.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can just reset properties by either setting them to an empty string:

```
document.getElementById('darkOverlay').style.backgroundColor = "";
document.getElementById('darkOverlay').style.opacity = "";
```

Or setting them to the default values you like:

```
document.getElementById('darkOverlay').style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
document.getElementById('darkOverlay').style.opacity = "1";
```

Answer (score 4):

```
document.getElementById("darkOverlay").removeAttribute("style");
```

Works fine for me...
Works only if you put your opacity attribute and background in style

Comment: Wrong solution. 
It will remove other styling effects with background.

Answer (score 3):

try

```js
document.getElementById('darkOverlay').style.backgroundColor= 'transparent';
document.getElementById('darkOverlay').style.opacity= 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var element = document.getElementById('darkOverlay');
element.style.backgroundColor = null;
element.style.opacity = null;
```

Comment: `element.style.background-color` is not a viable variable notation in Javascript. Use either `element.style.backgroundColor` or `element.style['background-color']`.